# Can I have multiple values/object assigned to a single Form Control?

Tags: angular, forms

I have a form with a mat-select, which on selection change, will save the item via the formControl. Once the form is processed it will save retain the new values selected in the drop down.  Originally I was just storing the number.

[value]="item.number"

I want to grab both the name and number from the items being displayed.  Can I have the FormControl save the whole object and then I can do a get("nameOfVar").value?  If not, how could I break it out so I grab both values but show both in the options like I have listed below?

````
<mat-form-field [ngClass]="{'error' : isInvalid}">
     <mat-label>NUMBER / NAME</mat-label>
          <mat-select [formControl]="serviceNumber" (selectionChange)="selectionChanged()">
                 <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items.serviceAreas" [value]="item">
                        {{item.number}} {{item.name}}
                  </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[ngValue]` to bind object to `mat-option` value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Reactive Forms, you can subscribe to value changes of that dropdown using the FormControl.

Remove `selectionChanged()` on the HTML side.

```
serviceNumber = new FormControl();

ngOnInit() {
  this.serviceNumber.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    if (value) {
       // Here you should have you whole object of 'item' from the HTML side since you are binding the value to 'item'

      console.log(item);
      console.log(item.name);
      console.log(item.number);
    }
  });
}
```